# How to find last date of current year in db2

Tags: sql, db2

I want to find the last date for current year. As of now i am doing it like below and it is giving me right result '2016-12-31'. but i want to know is there any possible function to do this -

```
SELECT date(substr(current_date,1, 4)||'-'|| '12-31')  FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly shorter and faster because of datetime function `YEAR`:

```
values(year(current_date) || '-12-31')
```

The above is for testing on the DB2 command prompt, a fully SELECT would be:

```
select year(current_date) || '-12-31' from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Comment: Do you really mean `values()`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: yes he does, it's standard SQL. `values(1)` is essentially the same as `select 1`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/6851

Comment: Data_henrik, you gave the same answer which was written in my question. I want to know is there any specific function to calculate it?

Comment: @Govind, I gave you a better way, without using `substr`.